# Are there any executor in java concurrent package which guarantee that all tasks will be done in order they were submitted?

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer, executorservice

A code sample for demonstration of the idea from the title:

```
executor.submit(runnable1);
executor.submit(runnable2);
```

I need to be sure that runnable1 will finish before runnable2 start and I haven't found any proofs of such behavior in the executors documentation.

About the problem I'm solving:
I need write lots of logs to a file. Each log requires much precomputing (formatting and some other stuff). So, I want to put each logging task to a kind of queue and process these tasks in a separate thread. And, of course, it's important to keep logs ordering.

Answer (score 4):

A single threaded executor will perform all tasks in the order submitted.  You would only use a thread pool with multiple threads if you wanted the tasks to be perform concurrently.

Adding tasks to a queue can be expensive in itself.  You can use an Exchanger like this

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/09/exchange-and-gc-less-java.html?z#!/2011/09/exchange-and-gc-less-java.html

This avoid using a queue or creating object.

An alternative which is faster is to use a memory mapped file which doesn't require a background thread (actually the OS is working in the background)  This is much faster again.  It supports sub-microsecond latencies and millions of messages per second.

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple wrapper like the one below so that all your Runnables are executed in the same thread (i.e. sequentially), and submit that wrapper to the executor instead. That does not address the logging issue.

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Runnable r) {
        runnables.add(r);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Runnable r : runnables) {
            r.run();
        }
    }

}

//......
MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
r.add(runnable1);
r.add(runnable2);
executor.submit(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are doing some post-analysis of the logfile? Have you considered not caring about the order they're written and re-ordering offline later. You could allocate a unique id at submit time using, a timestamp or AtomicLong?

a code sketch (untested) would look like this:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

class MyProcessor {

    public void work()
        for (Object data: allData) {
            executor.submit(new MySequencedRunnable(data);
        }
    }

}

class MySequencedRunnable implements Runnable {
    private static final AtomicLong LOG_SEQUENCE_ID = new AtomicLong(0);

    private final Object data;

    MySequencedRunnable(Object data) {
       this.data = data;

    }

    public void run() {
        LOGGER.log(LOG_SEQUENCE_ID.incrementAndGet(), data);
    }
```

}

Also consider, if you're using something like log4j, using [NDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html%22NDC%22) or [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html%22NDC%22) to assist with the re-ordering.